# How to choose a radio button using RCurl in an ajax event

Tags: html, ajax, r, forms, curl

Hi I have isolated an  tag containing a radio button and would like to select one of the options. Here is the full input path:

```
<input type="radio" id="gen" name="gen" value="Male" onclick="ajaxSetAge(this.value);" />
```

and I am using the following:

```
postForm("http://www.archersmate.co.uk/",
         radio = 'Female')
```

however this returns:

```
Error in nchar(str) : invalid multibyte string 1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to the `name` of the form field, not the `type`, like:

```
postForm('http://www.archersmate.co.uk', gen='Female')
```

That said, you won't be able to fill out the form on that website because it does not work as an HTTP POST request. Instead, it triggers an AJAX event. So, you're either going to have to go through the javascript and figure out if there's an underlying document you can access directly OR you'll have to use something like PhantomJS to trigger the relevant form fields and record the resulting javascript-generated contents.

Comment: thanks and thanks for saving me a lot of time figuring out why I can't fill the form in using the postForm function.